# Error al intentar crear una aplicación con npx

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, npm

Necesito ayuda he intentado crear una aplicación de react o next con npx creat-react/next-app, pero me sale el siguiente error.

### Este es el error tengo este otro error que me aparece

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USER\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-audit" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts@0.9.x"
npm ERR! node v16.13.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

npm ERR! core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script 'node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the core-js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs core-js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls core-js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Ya probé quitando el antivirus pero no funciono, tengo Windows 11 no creo que sea problema del sistema operativo, necesito una ayuda urgente.

Tengo la versión de node en (v16.13.2) y la versión de npm es (8.3.1)

Este error también me aparece al principio del otro error de arriba

```
 gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los pasos que seguiste al intentar crear una app de React y recibir ese error?

Comment: npx create-react-app, eso fue todo nada mas mi versión de npm es la (v16.13.2) antes funcionaba todo y ahora no se por que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema, pero me toco hacer todo esto.

1- Busque en mi disco local C todos los archivos que decían node,node-cahe,npm etc y los elimine.

2- Después desinstale node y lo volví a instalar pero seleccione la casilla que decía (Automatically install the necesary).

3- Instale Python mediante la Microsoft store, la verdad no se paraqué requiere Python si no manejo ese lenguaje de programación pero lo hice por que me salía errores como estos.

```
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
```

4- Fue a la terminal de powerShell  ejecute el siguiente comando (npm install npm@latest -g)

Answer (score 0):

Posibles soluciones:

Instala la versión más reciente de npm ya que tienes la version `npm  v2.15.12`
con el siguiente comando `npm install -g npm`. Luego intenta instalar nextjs mediante el comando:

```
   npx create-next-app@latest
   # or
   yarn create next-app
```

si tu proyecto a iniciar es en Typescript debes hacerlo mediante el comando:

```
   npx create-next-app@latest --typescript
   # or
   yarn create next-app --typescript
```

Fuente:[Documentacion Oficial](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started)

Comment: No me a funcionado, instale la ultima versión de npm ya sabiendo que ya la tenia instalada, pero lo hice para verificar si había algo mal instalado de npm pero igual no funciona me sale el mismo error. Mi versión de npm es la 8.3.1 ejecute esto y no funciono (npx create-next-app@latest)

Comment: Indagando mas sobre las posibles causas encontre esto en el portal de [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483917/how-to-solve-node-js-npm-npx-problem-you-are-using-npm-2-15-12-but-im-updated) @YOSIPMIKE.